# How do I calculate a random point that is a fixed distance from another point?

Tags: c#

I suppose by distance I mean radius, so another way of phrasing it would be "how do I get random points on the circumference of a circle of a given radius, given also the circles centre point".

I don't understand the markdowns.  This is a simple C# question that requires a simple C# answer as provided adequately by Daniel DiPaolo below.

Neither the markdowns nor the associated comments are helpful by way of improving the question or providing an answer.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: This is a geometry question. Why is this tagged with C#? Why is it even here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your center and radius are fixed, then really the only thing that's varying is the angle.  So, just calculate some random angle between 0 and 360 degrees (or 0 and 2π radians) and use that to get the x-y coordinates using the polar conversion.

```
x = r × cos( θ )
y = r x sin( θ )
```

Add the x,y coords of your center as the offset and you have your coordinates.

Answer (score 7):

Calculate a random angle and then use the angle and distance as a polar offset from the first point.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Circle Point Tracking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePointPicking.html) there's a few methods for picking points.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmic code

Given circle of {[0,0], 1} - {centre, radius}

1. **x** => Get random number x from [-1, 1]
2. **y+** or **y-** => Randomly select either positive or negative y quarter (0 or 1 for example)
3. **y** => Get intersection of vertical line x=X1 (from step 1) and circle, select either positive or negative quarter (from step 2)

**NB** This is can be done simpler, faster, and more uniformly distributed by using angles, see other answers.

The problem with my algorithm, in case anyone would try to use it, is that because of the bending shape of a circle, points close to `X=r+` and `X=r-` will be picked up less often than the one close to `X=0`. See comments by @Servy.

Comment: This won't result in each point on the circle having the same probability.    Points nearer to x=0 will be more likely than points near x=radius.  Not only is choosing an angle easier, but it makes ensuring equal probability much simpler as well.

Comment: @Servy could you please explain why points near `X=0` are more likely to occur than `X=r`?

Comment: The points are more dense, along the X axis, near x=r than they are on x=0.  Think of it this way, rather than a perfect circle imagine that you just had a polygon with say 100 edges.  Take the upper right quarter of that.  Draw a line from each point down to the X axis.  You will notice the lines are less dense on the left side and more dense on the right side.  As you increase the number of points on the polygon this property will remain (even up to infinity, which is a circle).

Comment: @Servy very good point (took me a few reads to understand it), this happens because of the bending shape of the circle (or polygon). I didn't see it initially because it is hard to trace it kind of backwards, I will mention this in the answer.

Comment: Points close to x=+r and x=-r will be *less* likely, not more likely.  Take my previous example of a polygon with vertical lines.  If you pick a random point on the X axis the "point" chosen will be the one with the line to the left of it.  Therefore the distance between the lines is the probability of that point being chosen.  When they are less dense (near x=0) the probability is higher.  When they are more dense the distance between the lines is smaller, so the probability of each individual line/point is smaller.